# How to avoid root element annotation while marshalling in JAXB?

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb

I want to store my object data to XML. Below code spinets will show the example of model class.

```
Class Model
{
  @XmlElement
  private int id;
  @XmlElement
  Private string name;
}
```

I will have multiple model objects which will be stored in some list as below

```
@XmlRootElement
Class ModelWrapper
{
  @XmlElement
  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = ListAdapter.class, type = List.class)
  List<model> list;
  public setlist(List<model>list)
  {
    //setting list
  }
  public List<model> getlist()
  {
    return list
  }
}
```

Now if I marshall this using JAXB, something like this will be produced:

```
<Modelwrapper>
  <List>
  ......
  ......
  </List>
</Modelwrapper>
```

I want to avoid one of the root may be list or Modelwrapper.
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Can you show us your Classes annotated?

Comment: How do you want your XML to look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this way your xml will be

```
<ModelWrapper>
   <model>
     ......
   </model>
   <model>
     ......
   </model>
</ModelWrapper>
```

ModelWrapper.java

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ModelWrapper {

    @XmlElement(name = "model")
    protected List<Model> list;
```

---

Test

ModelWrapper.java

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ModelWrapper", propOrder = {
    "list"
})
public class ModelWrapper {

    @XmlElement(name = "model")
    private List<Model> list;

    public List<Model> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<Model> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

}
```

Model.java

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Model", propOrder = {
    "id","name"
})
public class Model {
    @XmlElement
    private int id;
    @XmlElement
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Main.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {

        JAXBContext jc =  JAXBContext.newInstance(ModelWrapper.class);

        ModelWrapper mw = new ModelWrapper();

        List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();
        Model m = new Model();
        m.setId(1);
        m.setName("model1");
        list.add(m);
        m = new Model();
        m.setId(1);
        m.setName("model2");
        list.add(m);

        mw.setList(list);

        Marshaller mar = jc.createMarshaller();

        mar.marshal(mw, System.out);


    }

}
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<modelWrapper>
    <model>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>model1</name>
    </model>
    <model>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>model2</name>
    </model>
</modelWrapper>
```

Comment: Yes but i dont want the Model..That i wanted to avoid

Comment: @Rajesh In your question there is "I want to avoid one of the root may be list or Modelwrapper" .. in this way you are avoid list.

Comment: @Rajesh - Can you post exactly how you want your XML to look?